# What is the best way to implement Youku on React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, youku

I've done some research and I didn't find anything related to the Youku implementation that is updated (a lot of posts from 2016 and 2017). I didn't find any official SDK (React Native and neither iOS and Android) provided by Youku itself, it looks like there is nothing about it (or I can't find it).

At the moment my implementation is a WebView inside the page with a custom loader and an error message when something goes wrong.

Another problem is that from some videos an error compare and say

```
[Fail] The params of {vid,target,client_id} are necessary
```

How can I solve that error that sometimes appears? Again, I cannot find something about it.

Do you guys have something to suggest about it? There is some lost documentation that I can't find?

**My implementation at the moment:**

```js
export const YouKuPlayer: React.FC<YouKuPlayerProps> = ({ url, videoId }) => {
  const [showLoader, setShowLoader] = useState(true);
  const localizedStrings = useLocalizedStrings();

  const renderError = useCallback(() => {
    return <Loader noDataAvailable title={localizedStrings.errorCheckInternetConnection} />;
  }, [localizedStrings.errorCheckInternetConnection]);

  const youKuUrl = useMemo(() => {
    if (url) return url;
    return `https://player.youku.com/embed/${videoId}`;
  }, [url, videoId]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <WebView
        source={{
          html: `
          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
            <head>
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
              <style>
                iframe {
                  position:absolute;
                  top:0;
                  left:0;
                  width:100%;
                  height:100%;
                }
              </style>
            </head>
            <body>
              <iframe src="${youKuUrl}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </body>
          </html>
          `,
        }}
        onLoadEnd={() => setShowLoader(false)}
        renderError={renderError}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        bounces
        decelerationRate="normal"
        allowsFullscreenVideo
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
      />
      {showLoader && (
        <ActivityIndicator style={styles.spinnerBackground} size="large" color={COLORS.white} />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Have you tried to play the video with de video component from react native ?
You can give it an url

Comment: Hi @Poptocrack, there is not a problem in playing the video because of the WebView. The web view just open the default video player as you suggest and everything is ok, I just don't feel that is the correct way of doing it, most of the time for this sort of thing an SDK is usually offered, and YouKu is big enough to build one, but is Chinese and because of that I probably can't find the right info about it